# Is it possible to use && and || operators in the same if statement in Java?

Tags: java, operators

Im trying to check if `case1` and or `case2`

and came up with following code

```
if(case1 && || case2)..
```

but it doesn't seem to work, is it even possible to use two operators like this? if not are there any work around?

Comment: That also doesn't make any sense ... did you think about what you try to achieve? -> you can't use the operators like this. You know about boolean algebra?

Comment: So you want case1 and case2 to be true or case1 or case2 to be true? Your statement does not make any sense

Comment: and + or? WTF? You get this is boolean?

Comment: I just realised how dumb my question is, I guess what I tried to achieve was if something is case together with case1, or if it is just case1 or case2

Comment: If `case1` and `case2` are boolean (which they must be to be used as operands to `&&` or `||`), you can check if exactly one of them is true (exclusive-or) by simply doing `if (case1 != case2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Either both case1 `AND` case2 must be true `OR` one of them.

```
if (case1 || case2) {....}
```

Comment: I didn't realise or operator implemented and already, thank you

Comment: @Ilja: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of OR. OR doesn't "implement AND", it's just that "true OR true" is true; that's a property of OR, always has been, always will be.

Answer (score 1):

`||` is "and/or" already. You'd need to work to get "exclusive or" (a.k.a. XOR).

Answer (score 1):

AND/OR is the same as OR. You want `case1 || case2`:

```
case1    case2   case1 and case2   case1 or case2    case1 and/or case2
  0        0            0                0                 0
  0        1            0                1                 1
  1        0            0                1                 1
  1        1            1                1                 1
```

As you can see, this is simply an OR.

True OR true is true, that's just how OR works. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction.

There's no such thing as an "AND/OR". It sounds like perhaps you were confusing OR with exclusive-OR.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work and you dont need this either.

There are three conditions:

1. both condition true
2. any one of them is true
3. neither of them is true

For condition 1 `&&` operator

For condition 2 `||` operator

for condition 3 `~` of 2 condition. As all are mutual excusive you don't need what you have said.